# How to Insert and get the autoincremented primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to inset and get the id that's autoincrement in my database , is it possible ?

```
    Person.name = "Ali";
    entities.Person.add(Person);
    entities.SaveChanges();
```

the table has only name and PersonId , and after  `entities.SaveChanges();`I tought that PersonId will be filled automatically, but it's not the case, so even that the record is inserted in database, the PersonID is still null after `entities.SaveChanges();` is it how it should work ? or I miss something to  get the current PersonID

```
  public partial class Person
        {
            public Person()
            {               
            }
        
            public decimal PersonID{ get; set; }
            public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `PersonID` is DB generated?

Comment: yes, the row is inserted

Comment: May we have a look at `Person` class definition?

Comment: i've updated the post

Comment: why is the ID a decimal instead of int?

Comment: Your primary key deviates from the entity framework conventions. It is not an int. If you deviate from the conventions, you should inform entity framework about the deviations in `DbContext.OnModelCreating(...)`. Did you specify that PersonId is the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Try do mark the ID field as the following:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person() {}

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal PersonID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @user2848242 What is the value in DB?

Comment: each time i execute it , it's incremented by one, 77, next time is 78, but when i see  the object Person by adding a breakpoint , it's always 0.

Comment: @user2848242 What is the database? MySQL?

Comment: the database is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that Id is decimal, but should be int. Add attribute [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], recreate database and create new migration.

Comment: in oracle i set it as number and as int , for both types i got decimal in entity framework after generating the entities